# Detect enter key press on input field

Tags: javascript, html, css, iframe, input

I am working on an IFrame browser with an omnibox (id="address") and a "GO" button (id="submit"), and I would like to detect when the user presses enter and execute a JavaScript function. I have tried using the `<form>` tag and the [W3Schools How TO - Trigger Button Click on Enter](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_trigger_button_enter.asp), but the form broke my application, and the button click on enter didn't do anything.

Here's my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="https://docs.google.com/drawings/d/e/2PACX-1vSqg7iNwpB8zKiJqvtbSf0-YrM_hiRkPs_aHG0RLVvXX1YnHfRfpnqSbN6DwEqpdaOWN1wZttTA3MI3/pub?w=30&h=30" type="image/x-icon" name="favicon"/>
    <title>Lokean Web Browser</title>
    <style type="text/css" media="all">
    @import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Noto+Sans:400,400i,700&display=swap');
       body, html {width: 100%; height: 100%; margin: 0; padding: 0}
.first-row {position: absolute;top: 0; left: 0; right: 0; height: 25px; padding:13px; padding-right: 0px; font-family: 'Noto Sans'; sans-serif; background-color:#202124; color:white; position:fixed; z-index: 4;}
.second-row {position: absolute; top: 46px; left: 0; right: 0; bottom: 0;}
.second-row iframe {display: block; width: 100%; height: 100%; border: none;}
.form {
   float: right;
}
#logo {
   
}
body {
   background-color: #202124;
   color: white;
   font-family: Noto Sans;
}
}
.noSelect {
    
}
#address {
   border-radius: 11px;
   border-style: none;
   border-width: 1px;
   width: 300px;
   padding: 3px;
   color: black;
   background-color: white;
   font-size: 11px;
}
#address:focus {
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: white;
    outline: none;
}
#submit {
   border-radius: 11px;
   border-color: #FFC107;
   border-style: solid;
   border-width: 1px;
   padding: 3px;
   background-color: #FFC107;
   color: black;
   font-size: 11px;
   margin-left: 6px;
   margin-right: 13px;
}
input[type=submit] {
    width: 2em;  height: 2em;
}
#submit:hover {
   cursor: pointer;
   animation-name: fill-hover;
  animation-duration: 0.4s;  
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}
#submit:focus {
    outline: none;
}
#submit:active {
   animation-name: border-active;
  animation-duration: 0.25s;  
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}
@keyframes border-active {
  from {}
  to {border-color: #9A7E24; border-width: 3px; margin-left: 4px; margin-right: 11px;}
}
@keyframes fill-hover {
  from {}
  to {border-color: #E0A800; background-color: #E0A800;}
}
a {
   color: white;
}
#url {
    
}
.title {
   float: left;
   font-size: 19px;
   color: white;
}
.center {
   text-align: center;
}
</style>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
    var url;
    function view() {
       url = document.getElementById("address").value;
       var checkColon = url.includes(":");
       var youtube = url.includes("youtube.com/");
       var youtubeShort = url.includes("youtu.be/");
       var noSearch = url.includes(".") || url.includes(":");;
       var newUrl;
       var n;
       var s;
        if (noSearch !== true){
          url = "https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?search=" + url + "&title=Special%3ASearch";
       }
       if (checkColon !== true && noSearch == true){
          url = "http://" + url;
       }
       if (youtube == true) {
          n = url.indexOf('&');
          if (n !== -1) {
             url = url.substring(0, n);
          }
          newUrl = url.replace("/watch?v=", "/embed/");
          url = newUrl;
       }
       if (youtubeShort == true) {
          newUrl = url.replace("youtu.be/", "youtube.com/embed/");
          url = newUrl;
       }
       document.getElementById("url").src = url;
       document.getElementById("address").value = url;
           return false;
    }
    function iLoad() {
       url = document.getElementById("url").src;
       document.getElementById("address").value = url;
    }
    
</script>
</head>
<body>
 <div class="first-row">
  <span class="title" id="title">
     <img src="https://docs.google.com/drawings/d/e/2PACX-1vQ6gkadBIbBAYR28QDvj8FQRnJ51SL9qIFYJQMPtkMiiyRb9ezklHjM5qTY3jCblh6wCw6hTkDJWLQl/pub?w=72&amp;h=72" id="logo">
  </span>
  <span class="form">
<input onClick="this.setSelectionRange(0, this.value.length)" type="url" name="address bar" id="address" class="noSelect" value="" placeholder="Enter URL or search"/>
  <input type="submit" value="+" id="submit" onclick="view();">
  </span>
</div>
<div class="second-row">
<iframe id="url" title="Lokean Web" src="https://wikipedia.org" onLoad="iLoad();" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowpaymentrequest="true" allowfullscreen sandbox = "allow-forms allow-pointer-lock allow-same-origin allow-scripts allow-top-navigation" ></iframe>
<div class="center">
<br>
Lokean Web Browser unblocks Youtube and all GoGuardian-blocked websites, and uses Wikipedia for search purposes.
<br>
However, some websites refuse to connect because this is an iFrame browser.
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Thank you for your time and any help! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can do something like:

```js
const inputEl = document.getElementById("enter-input");

inputEl.addEventListener("keyup", manageEnter);

function manageEnter(evt) {
  evt.preventDefault();
  if (evt.keyCode === 13) {
    console.log("hello");
  }
}
```

```html
<form onsubmit="event.preventDefault();" action="">
  <input id="enter-input" type="string" />
</form>
```

To test, do click in the input and press enter to see a console.log, if you press any other key, the console.log doesn't will be trigger.

Comment: That might work, but I can't type in the input box. Is that because of the preventDefault?

Comment: @confermusearename I made a modification, the problem was the type of event in the addEventListener, instead of keydown, you need to use keyup.